# Persistence of Redirect URL when redirecting after a POST and passing data

Tags: django, django-forms, http-post, http-redirect

Upon successful submission of a form, I redirect to a "success" page that display a 'thank you' message along with some information about the submission. To do this, I put the POST data in session, Redirect to the appropriate URL, and then render the template using the session data.

But, this means that if someone manually navigates to the 'success' URL, they will see the "success" message from that previous form submission. How do I prevent that? The form is processed at `/register/`. Successful submissions are redirected to `/register/success`. I want people who physically type `/register/success/` in their browser (without having submitted a form) to see an error page or something. How can this be handled?

urls.py

```
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^register/success/$', views.registration_success, name='registration_success'),
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if the_form.is_valid():
            my_id = the_form.cleaned_data['myid']
            email_addr = the_form.cleanedJ_data['emailaddr']
            request.session['registration'] = {'my_id': my_id, 'email_addr': email_addr }

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:registration_success'))


def registration_success(request):
    template = loader.get_template('polls/submitted.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, request.session.get('registration'))
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Django session to achieve that.Here is the example by using your code.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if the_form.is_valid():
            my_id = the_form.cleaned_data['myid']
            email_addr = the_form.cleanedJ_data['emailaddr']
            request.session['registration'] = {'my_id': my_id, 'email_addr': email_addr }
            request.session['form-submitted'] = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:registration_success'))


def registration_success(request):
    if not request.session.get('form-submitted', False):
        # handle the case where there is no form submitted
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:register'))
    template = loader.get_template('polls/submitted.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, request.session.get('registration'))
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: @edwinlunardo thank you! In the case where there is no form submitted, does the second argument to the "get" set `form-submitted` to false? (not sure how that default "False" value there works...I also want to make sure to set `form-submitted` to False after someone submits the form and sees the "success page" because I don't want them to navigate back to that page later on...?

Comment: The second argument do not set the `form-submitted` into `False`, but if the `get` method do not return the `form-submitted` key, it will return the second argument. We can say it is the default value for no key.